# SQL Many To Many Select With Link Table

Tags: sql, search, stored-procedures, many-to-many, sql-match-all

I am trying to make my keyword search as efficient as possible using the following 3 tables :

**tblImageFiles**
[ID,
ImageURL]

**tblTags**
[ID,Tag]

**tblxImagesTags**
[ID, ImageID, TagID] (this is a linktable joining the above in a many-to-many relationship)

Can anyone help me out with a stored procedure to return ALL images which match ALL search tags entered based on this schema?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question (with lots of ways to do this): [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number in the `count(distinct aux.TagID)` must be equal to the number of tags in `where t.Tag in (tag1, tag2, tag3)`.

```
select img.* from tblImageFiles img
inner join (
   select it.ImageID from tblTags t
   inner join tblxImagesTags it on it.TagID = t.ID
   where t.Tag in (tag1, tag2, tag3)
   group by it.ImageID
   having count(distinct it.TagID) = 3
) aux on aux.ImageID = img.ID
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting the following message when I run the query :

Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'IF'

Any ideas?

Comment: @Mike yes I corrected. I was using if as an alias but it's a reserved key. And I alter the code to put it like you wanted.

Comment: Ah, this works but same issue as with Matts suggestion, it returns images matching any of the tags rather than filtering, any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Mike have you used the `group by` query? Try it again. If you put more tags you need to replace the `3` by the total number of tags.

Comment: sorry about that I hadn't refreshed the page until after I posted my reply :/  if I paste your query I get this error :  "The multi-part identifier "aux.ImageID" could not be bound.. not sure what is causing it though..!

Comment: @Mike in Sybase in worked well :P I've replace the outer aux by aux2, now it should work for you.

Comment: It's wrong. There is no `aux` alias or table, anywhere in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
        SELECT tblImageFiles.ImageURL
          FROM tblImageFiles
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblxImagesTags
            INNER JOIN tblTags
                    ON tblTags.ID = tblxImagesTags.TagID
                 WHERE tblxImagesTags.ImgageID = tblImageFiles.ID
                   AND tblTags.Tag = <searchtag1>)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblxImagesTags
            INNER JOIN tblTags
                    ON tblTags.ID = tblxImagesTags.TagID
                 WHERE tblxImagesTags.ImgageID = tblImageFiles.ID
                   AND tblTags.Tag = <searchtag2>)
                // etc...
```

The derived table could be separated out, but the syntax for that depends on what DB you are using. You also need to run a loop to make sure you can cope with a variable number of search terms, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: thanks, this seems close but returns images matching any of the tags, I need it to match all of them if possible so, for example, searching 'Door' should produce more results than 'Red, Door' as it should filter